# For Each Cell Value: Repeat a Range of Values

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm tasked with creating a spreadsheet to keep track of employee hours for every day in a given date range (typically 1 week). For each day in that range, I need all the employee's names written out, and then a slot to write their hours next to their name. Essentially, I need each employee's name written out as many times as there are days. I imagine it looking somewhat like this, where the days, dates, and names are all written out for me automatically.

-- Example Data --

**Dates** - 9/10/2023 | 9/11/2023 | 9/12/2023 | 9/13/2023 | 9/14/2023 | 9/15/2023 | 9/16/2023

**Days** - Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday

**List of Employees** - Jack | Donald | Mike | Philip

| 9/10/2023 | Sunday |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 8 Hours |
| Donald | 4 Hours |
| Mike | 0 Hours |
| Philip | 8 Hours |

| 9/11/2023 | Monday |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 0 Hours |
| Donald | 4 Hours |
| Mike | 8 Hours |
| Philip | 0 Hours |

| 9/12/2023 | Tuesday |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 2 Hours |
| Donald | 8 Hours |
| Mike | 0 Hours |
| Philip | 8 Hours |

-- so on for each day --

I'm somewhat new to Google Sheets, but I have spent a few hours working on this and I have gotten past most of the hurdles – except for the part where I have to auto-generate the list.

So far -

I have all the **dates auto-generating** using this formula:

```
// Writes all the dates starting from the given start date (E2), for as many given days (D2) 
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(SEQUENCE(D2, 1, E2, 1)))
```

I have all the **days auto-generating** using this formula:

```
//Writes all the days for the each of the corresponding dates, starting from the start date (E2), for as many given days (D2)
=ARRAYFORMULA(switch(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(D2, 1, E2, 1)), 1, "Sunday", 2, "Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday", 7, "Saturday"))
```

I have a **reference** to all the **worker names** using this formula:

```
// Gets a list of all the workers by using an indirect reference by using the counted items (D5) + where the list starts (E5)
=ArrayFormula(E5:INDIRECT("E"&ROW(E5)+D5)&{""})
```

I know I have all the basic information needed to make this work, but I just don't know how to put it all together to make exactly what I need. Help would be greatly appreciated, because this problem is beyond my current knowledge. Hopefully I have provided enough detail!

I tried doing research into similar problems and different solutions people have had, [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169021/repeat-a-sequence-n-times) seemed like everything I needed, but it was so complicated that I couldn't figure it out; all I ended up getting was various different errors.

I also tried [repeating and flattening the array](https://youtu.be/gLOvBBcPKh4?si=cYVECJR6ELkzutV2), but that didn't have the effect I wanted, as it had all the days listed out, then all the days, followed by all the employees written in a single column, which made it pretty much useless.

It ended up looking somewhat like this:

9/11/2023

9/12/2023

9/13/2023

9/14/2023

...

Sunday

Monday

Tuesday

...

Jack

Donald

Mike

Philip

etc...

Here is a [copy of my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ax0-ydzY45R3GDt6DJfasert-fxY2xKKdkUTDJo87OM/edit?usp=sharing), with editor access, as well a manually made example. I very much appreciate any answers!

--

**Edit**: A [solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xVVX4Dten5I2yuQRvAmIazzjFPORj0S4nOojjJmKTH4/edit?usp=sharing) has been found! Much appreciated for all of the responses. Feel free to use it to your hearts content!

Additionally, here's a [version with editor access](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KaA-LDZXlcGFL9z4ib2XVeHhN2E5rJjOICurWhySASM/edit?usp=sharing). Enjoy!

Comment: the desired result is somewhat awkward and does not make much sense ... have you considered putting the four names in the first column, Monday in second column, Tuesday in third column, etc. etc.? ... that way, all hours worked are in a row for each employee

Comment: The sample data refers to four employees. Is this a fixed number?

Comment: No, the number of employees is a variable number that changes from week to week!

Comment: I'm really pleased that you found a solution. Would you please consider posting an answer, or a provide a link to the site where you found the solution. Sad to say, but over time, sometimes users delete sheets that were referenced in their questions, and this limits the pay-forward value of the question and its answer.

Comment: Regarding you solution. I used the sample data in the spreadsheet and then added an extra employee. Other than for the first day, the effect is to push all the data entry down so that the rows not longer align. Is this an issue? I guess this would also have the opposite effect if you deleted an employee.